# How to patch classes in different modules at once - Java 9 - Jigsaw

Tags: java, javac, java-9, java-platform-module-system

Say I have the following directory structure, each package having several java class files.

```
src
+- classes
   +- java
      +- io
      +- lang
      +- util
          +- function
          +- logging
              +- FileHandler.java
```

So according [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start):

- `java.util` exists in `java.base`
- `java.util.logging` exists in `java.logging`
- `java.util.function` exists in `java.base`

There are examples on overriding single file, like:

```
   javac --patch-module java.base=src -d mypatches/java.base \
        src/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java
```

Is there convenient way to do this when there are several files which belongs to different modules?

Comment: You can use --patch-module in conjunction with --module-source-path but you've got the sources for two modules in the same tree. I'm curious what this is though as it seems a bit dangerous to be patching these modules like this.

Comment: @reversiblean Your intent also matters since *The `--patch-module` option is intended only for testing and debugging. Its use in production settings is strongly discouraged.*

Comment: @nullpointer it is for a model testing application. so is required.

Comment: What is "model testing" and why does it require modifications to the java.base and java.logging modules?

Comment: https://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki/intro/start

Comment: I don't see any specifics on that page to indicate why it needs to add classes to these modules. I would assume a project like this using bytecode instrument and java.lang.instrumentation.